# disable "this document has been modified"-message

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I am changing the content on my webbrowser control using 2 different methods. I am only able to disable the message in one situation.
**method 1:** 
I just need to add some text at the bottom of the page (i don't get the message)

```
string s = browser.DocumentText + "<a>Extra Text</a>";
browser.Document.Write(string.Empty);  
browser.DocumentText=s;
```

**method 2:** 
When i try to create a new element and add it to the webbrowser I still get the "this document has been modified"-message. Can i disable this message?

```
HtmlElement element = browser.Document.GetElementById("myId");
HtmlElement newElement = browser.Document.CreateElement("a");
newElement.InnerText = "Extra text";
element.AppendChild(newElement);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
myWebBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Refresh", False, "")
```